# Causes of differences in sizes and functionality of 2 APK files from same code?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, apk

I have a very interesting problem. I'm working on an Android app for a company project. The basic process looks like this. Our main engineer writes his code and pushes to github, I pull that code and change version numbers, turn on google analytics and crashlytics and release it on the play store after testing. I figure this is a typical workflow, however today we ran into an issue. When I built my project from his code, I ran into a problem in the app (if force closed a black screen appears when relaunched). So I reported the problem, but he could not reproduce it. So we sent it around the office for testing. Anyone who used my built .apk had the black screen problem. Anyone who used his build did not have the black screen problem. The issue is we are using the exact same code off of GitHub. Another one of our developers decided to build the project and also got the black screen error (like my .apk build).

**Things to Note:**

-We're both using eclipse

-We are both targeting android 5.0

-We are using the same libraries

-I've tried using the code in github without making my usual version/analytics changes and get the same results, it is the exact same code.

-We both believe we're not doing any 'special' build, and we've been doing this process for a while without any problems like this.

-Reverting to an old version of the code does not seem to fix this (this problem has not always existed.)

**Possible Explanations (Existent differences):**

-I have a crashlytics plugin in eclipse that is used for this application (I do not believe this is the issue, as our other developer did not have this plugin either and I built on a laptop without it and did not resolve the black screen issue.)

-The sizes of the two built .apk's is different. Mine (the one with the error) is larger by about 500kb. (I assume this reflects the problem but does not actually help to solve it.)

**Focus Question:**

*I think it best to ask this question to determine the root problem at hand.*

What could be the cause of the same code building different .apk files in terms of functionality (one with a bug, one without) and in terms of size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look at the logcat for bugs.  It's fairly infrequent in my experience for a bug to be that obvious and not make some noise in the logcat.
2. "We're both using the same libraries".  One common cause of this could be if you use libraries you've gotten from remote repos and your versions are more recent and have a bug.  That woudl also explain the size difference.
3. Look at the apks.  You can rename them into .zip files and just look inside them after unzipping.

Comment: You actually nailed it, except I'm still not sure how it happened. We were somehow using different versions of google-play-service his was an older version and mine was newer (even though we should have both been using the one from our repo?). Anyways it ended up being [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82157) manifesting without any logcat errors. Thanks!